# Gtk+-3.0 seems work well in mingw64, however, the gcc build the code fail due to some undefined reference to issue

Tags: c, gcc, gtk3, mingw-w64

System: Win10 + Mysy64 + mingw64 + gtk+3.0

When I checked that below are ok as shown below, it seems work well.

> ```
> pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0
> ```

```
C:\msys64>pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0
-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/pango-1.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/glib-2.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/harfbuzz -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/freetype2 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/libpng16 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/fribidi -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/cairo -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/lzo -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/pixman-1 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/atk-1.0 -mms-bitfields
```

> ```
> pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
> ```

```
C:\msys64>pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
-LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lsetupapi -lcfgmgr32 -lhid -lwinspool -lcomctl32 -lcomdlg32 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

When I try to build below code, errors shown, may I know how to fix it, thank you.

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main() {
    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Build command in code::blocks:

```
 gcc.exe -LC:\msys64\mingw64 -o bin\Debug\gtk.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lsetupapi -lcfgmgr32 -lhid -lwinspool -lcomctl32 -lcomdlg32 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

```
||=== Build: Debug in gtk (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\..\lib\crt2.o:crtexe.c|| undefined reference to `__mingw_init_ehandler'|
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\..\lib\crt2.o:crtexe.c|| undefined reference to `__security_init_cookie'|
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\..\lib\crt2.o:crtexe.c|| undefined reference to `__security_init_cookie'|
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\..\lib\crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.mingw_app_type[.refptr.mingw_app_type]+0x0)||undefined reference to `mingw_app_type'|
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\..\lib\crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.mingw_initcharmax[.refptr.mingw_initcharmax]+0x0)||undefined reference to `mingw_initcharmax'|
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\..\lib\crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.mingw_initltssuo_force[.refptr.mingw_initltssuo_force]+0x0)||undefined reference to `mingw_initltssuo_force'|
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\..\lib\crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.mingw_initltsdyn_force[.refptr.mingw_initltsdyn_force]+0x0)||undefined reference to `mingw_initltsdyn_force'|
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\..\lib\crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.mingw_initltsdrot_force[.refptr.mingw_initltsdrot_force]+0x0)||undefined reference to `mingw_initltsdrot_force'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 9 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 5 second(s)) ===|
```

The build command is generated in code::blocks.
In code::blocks, I set `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` under Compiler setting -> Other compiler options,  and `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` under Linker setting -> Other linker options. so the build command is combined by these two flags.

Comment: What is your build command? Did you include all the flags you show above?

Comment: I have tried two ways: 1. command line, 2 code:block with specific compile option: pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0, and link opton: pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0

Comment: You can use the `edit` button below your question to add missing information. Like the command line you used. (The complete and exact command you use to run the compiler)

Comment: Just add build command in code::blocks

Comment: The options don't look too bad. I am not sure about the first few references but the last ones don't refer to GTK3 at all. Maybe there is some version conflict as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72517499/program-compilation-error-undefined-references-using-mingw)

Comment: I add the setting about the code::blocks. and for version conflict, could you please advise how to check it, thank you